# Event handling in dynamically generated page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, jquery-events

I have a div with class called 'taglines' which is contained in a div with class called 'container'. When 'taglines' is clicked, it navigates to another page. The problem is the events on this new page are not responding after navigation. The following is the code that I am using to navigate:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.container').on('click', '.tagLines', function(){
       window.location = "manageMarks.php";
   });
}
```

The following is the code with the event that is refusing to work after navigation:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').on('click', '.loadSub', function(){
        alert('Clicked');
    });
});
```

However, If i use ajax to load the new  view I want, the events do eventually work. The following is the ajax I code I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.container').on('mouseover', '.tagLines', function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'manageMarks.php',
             data: {
             videoCode: $(this).attr('data-code')
            }, 
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                $('.container').html(data);             
            }
        }).error(function(){
            alert('An Error Has Occured');
        });
});
```

How can I get it to work without using ajax?

Comment: do you have any errors in the browser console? have you included jQuery in manageMarks.php?

Comment: no errors, and yes the jquery is included/added.

Comment: If you are adding content to your page after you have created your event handler(s) and then expecting your new content to be included in your event handling then you will need to use deferred event handling, or destroy/recreate your event handler(s)

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing a full page reload? If so your events would need to be wired up again. If not they should get wired up to dynamically loaded content.

Comment: yes, i am doing a full page reload and that's the one that is not working. How do i wire them after i do the full page reload.

Comment: The subsequent view would also need an $(document).ready(....) and you would need to wire all the events up again. All javascript state (including events) is lost when you navigate to a new page. This is not the case with AJAX requests since you are not leaving the page.

Comment: thank you @garryp u led me to my mistake. it works now